# Why does <div> seem to be preferred over <nav> for navigation bars?

Tags: html, navbar, nav

According to what I've read so far, `<nav>` seems to be better, but every single example I see on the Internet uses `<div ...="nav[igation]">`.

Is it just me seeing things or do people really use `<div>` ?
If so, is there a reason why ?

**EDIT** : just in case someone was wondering, of course I'm talking about navigation bars, and nav can't replace div in other cases...

Comment: Any particular reason for downvoting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<nav>` is newer. Lots of people haven't caught up yet. (Or are stuck having to cater to versions of Internet Explorer that Microsoft no longer supports)

Comment: If it contains site or page navigation, yes.

Answer (score 1):

`<nav>` is not a generic replacement for `<div>` (or vice-versa). It's a semantic element that should be used for **navigation**.

> The HTML `<nav>` element represents a section of a page whose purpose
>   is to provide navigation links, either within the current document or
>   to other documents. Common examples of navigation sections are menus,
>   tables of contents, and indexes ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)).

`<div>` has been around much longer than `<nav>`, which was introduced in HTML5, and is intended to be used as a generic container.

Comment: Yes of course. Maybe that's why I was downvoted as well. I edited to be clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Downvoter care to share what's not correct about this answer?